# How to simulate Mouse Acceleration?

Tags: objective-c, mouse, acceleration

I've written iPhone - Mac, Client - Server app that allows to use mouse via touchpad.

Now on every packet sent I move cursor by pecific amount of pixels (now 10px).
It isn't accurate. When i change sensitivity to 1px it's to slow.

I am wondering how to enhance usability and simulate mouse acceleration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest the following procedure:

**ON THE IPHONE:**

1. Determine the distance moved in `x` and `y` direction, let's name this `dx` and `dy`.
2. Calculate the total distance this corresponds to: `dr = sqrt(dx^2+dy^2)`.
3. Determine how much time has passed, and calculate the speed of the movement: `v = dr/dt`.
4. Perform some non-linear transform on the velocity, e.g.: `v_new = a * v + b * v^2` *(start with `a=1` and `b=0` for no acceleration, and then experiment for optimal values)*
5. Calculate a new distance: `dr_new = v_new * dt`.
6. Calculate new distances in `x`/`y` direction:
   `dx_new = dx * dr_new / dr` and `dy_new = dy * dr_new / dr`.
7. Send `dx_new` and `dy_new` to the Mac.

**ON THE MAC:**

1. Move the mouse by `dx_new` and `dy_new` pixels in `x`/`y` direction.

**NOTE:** This might jitter a lot, you can try averaging the velocity after step (3) with the previous two or three measured velocities if it jitters to much.

Comment: As far as I understand, there is going to be a little fluctuation. If I measure distance and velocity - packet will be sent after specific action (until move ends?).

Mouse must move simultaneously with finger on the touch screen.

Comment: To make it clear. I store previous X and Y position and time of touch, and make the calculation with current touch x,y and current touch time. It works perfectly.